# Vuforia query to fetch id of matching target

Tags: javascript, php, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

Creating a simple web "application" and integrating it with Vuforia using the web api. I managed to add targets to cloud dataset. But I am struggling to create the right query where I send an image from my laptop and get the id of its matching target in the cloud dataset.

Anyone with more experience in this who can point me at the naïve flaw?

Here are the 3 files:

**1) main.js:**

```js
document.getElementById('uploadForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData();
    let imageFile = document.getElementById('imageUpload').files[0];
    formData.append('image', imageFile);

    fetch('query_vuforia.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('Vuforia response:', jsonData);
        if (jsonData.error) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + jsonData.error;
            console.error('HTTP Response Code:', jsonData.httpCode || 'Unknown error code');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
    });
});
```

**2) query_vuforia.php**

```php
<?php
require_once 'SignatureBuilder.php';

// Authentication keys
$access_key = '*******************';
$secret_key = '**********************';

// URL for the Vuforia Query API
$url = "https://cloudreco.vuforia.com";
$requestPath = "/v1/query";

if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    $image = new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'image/jpeg', 'image.jpg');

    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $requestPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['image' => $image]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Create the date and signature
    $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
    $dateString = $date->format('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
    $sb = new SignatureBuilder();
    $signature = $sb->tmsSignature($requestPath, 'POST', $image, 'multipart/form-data', $date, $secret_key);
    
    // Set headers for the query request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: VWS ' . $access_key . ':' . $signature,
        'Date: ' . $dateString
    ]);

    // Execute the query request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for cURL errors and process the response
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch)]);
    } else {
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
        if ($httpCode === 200) {
            // Process and output the response
            echo json_encode($responseData);
        } else {
            // Include the httpCode in the JSON response for the JS to use
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error querying target.', 'httpCode' => $httpCode]);
        }
    }

    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error: No image uploaded or file error.']);
}
?>
```

**3) SignatureBuilder.php**

```php
<?php

class SignatureBuilder {

    public function tmsSignature($requestPath, $method, $contentType, $date, $secret_key) {
        // For multipart/form-data, the content is an empty string
        $content = "";

        // The body's MD5 hash is not needed for multipart/form-data, an empty string is used
        $hexDigest = md5($content, false);

        // Construct the string to sign.
        $toDigest = $method . "\n" . $hexDigest . "\n" . $contentType . "\n" . $date->format("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" . "\n" . $requestPath;

        // SHA1 hash, transformed from hexadecimal to Base64.
        $shaHashed = base64_encode(pack('H*', hash_hmac("sha1", $toDigest, $secret_key)));

        return $shaHashed;
    }
}
?>
```

I tried to apply what is explained in the documentation link below, but it didn't work:

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/web-api/vuforia-query-web-api

What I'm expecting is that once I select an image, post it to Vuforia, I get the right message from vuforia (including whether there is a match and what is the target id of the matching marker in the cloud dataset).